# Content of h1 tag is invisible until moused over in IE 6

Tags: css, text, internet-explorer-6, mouseover

The bizarre symptom I'm seeing [on this page](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/websvn/) (only when viewing with IE 6) is that the text of the `<h1>` tag is invisible when the page is loaded or resized, but appears when I mouse over the region where it appears in the upper-left corner. I haven't seen this with any other browser, and the only CSS attributes I'm modifying for any h1 tag are these:

- font-size
- font-weight
- margin, margin-top
- padding, padding-top, padding-bottom

Nowhere do I change `visible` or `display`, and there are no hover effects for the h1. Even the non-link text inside the header disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeing with John's post. I have (by sheer luck) been able to circumvent this debugging process on occasion by giving the element `position: relative` or `position: static` rules.

So you may want to cross your fingers and give that a whirl before going down John's route.

Comment: Two words: "black magic". Adding `position: relative;` to my `#header h1` rule caused it to appear in IE6 as expected. Thanks a million for the tip! :-D

Answer (score 5):

More than likely this is being caused by another styled element on the page.

I think your best option is trial and error... Removing all styles from the page, verifying the h1 element is no longer disappearing, and then re-adding the other styles until you've found the culprit

Comment: +1 In general practice I'd agree. Unfortunately, IE6 usually requires far more debugging time than I'm willing to spend to get things working. Fortunately, Mark was able to provide a bit of sorcery that solved things without going down this path. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything blatantly obvious but you do have rgba being applied via an hover.

```
#header #info a:hover, #header #info h2#pathlinks a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(63,63,63,0.35);
}
```

Also, this works locally with my IE6 so I'm not sure if maybe it behaves differently due to the associated zone in Internet Explorer (intranet, trusted, Internet).

I wholeheartedly agree with the other posters that this will be an exercise in debugging.  I like John's technique of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging help. The alpha might be screwing with IE6's mind, but thankfully Mark's answer was able to fix the issue. (I've ben testing it on localhost as well, and it worked the same in both situations.)

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see a `hasLayout` attribute listed for the heading, you may want to try adding `zoom:1;` to the `h1` and see what results you get. This made the text visible for me consistently when testing.

Indeed this problem seems pretty bizarre.