# Content Does Not Load Until Mouse Hover or Resizing Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site that uses a lot of javascript, and I suspect some of the code is interfering with loading the content. The site sometimes loads fine, but sometimes only the images show up, but the text content does not. It does only when I hover over where the text is supposed to be, or resize the browser. I'd post a code, but I'm not even sure which part to post.

This is a link to the site:

http://paraboladesignstudio.ipage.com/yahaira

I'd appreciate any leads.

Comment: Sorry I can't do much because I'm on my tablet but sometimes js / jQuery problems happen in e.g. wordpress due to conflicts. Have a look at wordpress jquery no conflict

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have solved the problem! [Content of h1 tag is invisible until moused over in IE 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323947/content-of-h1-tag-is-invisible-until-moused-over-in-ie-6)

Comment: Although I had the problem in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I cancel what what I've said. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added position: relative and height:100% to the element that didn't show up properly (for example, "aside"), and since then the problem hasn't happened.